# UE4 Blueprint / Variable Communication Issues

Tags: unreal-4, blueprints

So I have a system set up in my game that whenever the character collects an object the monster begins to speedup and this is used for each object that player must pickup, although I'm having issues getting the variable for the monsters speed to change when the item is picked up

I need a system so that once the item is picked up it changes the float variable of the monsters movement so he moves faster, also the next item appears that is also able to speed up the monster

I've attempted using a blueprint userface which I assume is the right choice to go for, but I still don't fully understand it's workings

I'm still very new to blueprints so sorry if they seem all over the place

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image: Monster Blueprint for location and rotation]Monster Blueprint for location and rotation, the variable 'Speedup' is the input that changes the speed of the monster

[image: Pickup Item Blueprint] Pickup Item Blueprint, a bit all over the place sorry for that I was testing tons of different methods but none of them turned out to work

[image: Pickup Item Function] Pickup Item Function

Comment: I'm posting extra ss here because of reputation limitations for amount of ss per post

Comment: http://puu.sh/sgtR3/715b9ca80d.png Pickup Item Function

Comment: I took care of your image limit problem.  It might make sense to digest your screenshots into text descriptions and add that to your post.  You might accidentally solve your own problem that way too; it's a form of rubber ducking.